# Is there any information on when the Ubuntu One Music Store will add more countries?

Tags: rhythmbox, ubuntu-one

According to the Ubuntu One Music Store help page, the following stores are currently available:

- UK - Purchase songs in EUR.
- US - Purchase songs in USD.
- Germany - Purchase songs in EUR.
- EU - Purchase songs in EUR. The countries in this region do not match the actual definition of the European Union. Customers in Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Finland, Estonia, France, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland, Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, and Switzerland will use this store.
- World - Purchase songs in EUR. Customers in countries not covered by the rest of the regional stores will use this store.

However, that doesn't include my country... and there's a note further down:

> More country-specific regional stores will be added after the launch of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Is there any information on what those are and when they're getting added?

Comment: My guess would be countries that already have a local 7digital store (listed at the [bottom of the 7digital site](http://7digital.com/)) are likely to be first, but that's just a guess...

Comment: I asked somebody hwho knows to comment. :)

Comment: @JanC: My country has one... so here's hoping :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry. Still no news. Since launching the initial set of regions, we've learned that the main challenge with managing more stores is the time it takes to keep the merchandising pages somewhat fresh with music that customers care about.

We have made some progress on this front recently, though, and hope to devote some time soon to overcome this obstacle so we can move forward with more stores. I know many people are interested in this so I'll post something on the Ubuntu One blog as soon as I have more specific information.

Comment: You can ask users to submit the songs they listen to (à la last.fm) to find out what's popular, you could even have an algorithm that suggest songs based on the listening habits of the user combined with that of other users with similar listening habits, etc.  (Something like that should be opt-in of course.)

Comment: Does every country/region really need there own store front. I'm sure Australia/New Zealand can happily sit in the same store as the US or UK. Really all we want to have the licensing extended to our countries. A special New Zealand store would be great, but I don't expect, nor need it. I just want to be able to buy music. I'm not even fussy on the currency.

Comment: @Kyle - The different storefronts is because of how artists license their music. If their terms are the same for all countries, then they could be part of the world store. Perhaps there might be a sizable number of artists that license their music the same for Australia and New Zealand. Then a combined store would make sense. When we're at the point of expanding the store, I'll look into it. Thanks for your question and comments.

Comment: This answer is nearly three years old. Any updates?